# Redirect module/action/ to module/action

Tags: routes, seo, symfony-1.4

My question is simple, how do I achieve SEO optimizing tasks with symfony 1.4?

The first problem, which isn't only a SEO problem but rather a symfony 1.4 in general is that symfony does a strange thing with URLs like:

> module/action

AND

> module/action/

The first one works, the second one is rejected or throws an error, OR what is most common works, but does not redirect (with a 301) to the first one, which should be a convention, since SEO-wise those urls are not identical.
This shouldn't be.

Comment: What error does it throw ? can you include your `routing.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a common error in symfony, this trailing slash can cause trouble. Some will tell you that this is normal because the first one is a *file* and the second one is a *directory*. Since you can't browse directory with symfony, it throw an error.

But you have two options as a work around, use htaccess or use a custom routing.

**htaccess:** (from [here](http://symfony-blog.driebit.nl/2010/07/url-routes-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash/))

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**custom routing:** (from [here](http://vacskamati.blogspot.fr/2010/05/how-to-allow-trailing-slash-in-urls-in.html))

`/apps/frontend/config/factories.yml`

```
all:
  routing:
    # class: sfPatternRouting
    class: myPatternRouting
```

Create the class:

`apps/frontend/lib/myPatternRouting.class.php`

```
<?php
class myPatternRouting extends sfPatternRouting
{
  protected function normalizeUrl($url)
  {
    $url = parent::normalizeUrl($url);

    // remove trailing slash
    $url = preg_replace('/\/$/', '', $url);

    return $url;
  }
}
```